# How to display one <ul> list into unlimited columns?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I'm using Django for backend and I want to display the below ul in unlimited columns with overflow-x : auto.

```html
<ul class="list">
  {% for i in skills %}
    <li>{{i}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**sample output:**

```html
1 7  . . . 
2 8  . . .
3 9  . . .
4 10 . . .
5 11 . . .
6 12 . . .
```

Comment: I think you can run another outer for loop for columns.

Comment: always 6 rows? ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif , the duplicate answer is missing the overflow requirement ;) (part of the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use grid

```css
ol {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(6,auto);
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-auto-columns:100px;/* need here to set a value so it can do next rule*/
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
</ol>
```